# What to do when a toe-kick saw doesn't fit underneath cabinets?

Tags: kitchens, cabinets, hardwood-refinishing

I have hardwoods in my kitchen that I want to refinish. The only problem is that there is a plywood layer with laminate tile on top of the wood. The plywood goes all the way to the wall, but we don't have the budget to replace the cabinets. 
I bought a 3 3/8ths in toe-kick saw to try to cut the plywood, but it won't fit underneath the cabinets.

What should my next move be?

Comment: A photo may help. With most cabinets the kick is part of the cabinet, are you sure it is a separate piece?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get one of the 'sonic tool' saws. That should fit. Buy 3-4 aggresive blades to cut that much floor.

Here's a link to one. There are many out there. Make sure you get a corded model, with the fastest 'rpms'.

https://www.rockwelltools.com/saws-sanders/sanders/sonicrafter-f80-oscillating-tool-rk5151k.html

Comment: I had thought about one of these, but wasn't sure it would work. Thanks for the help. I will go buy one tonight and try it!